# font-size different in -webkit and -moz browsers

Tags: html, css, firefox, google-chrome, jquery-ui-datepicker

Check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8ubbW/15/embedded/result/)

Why is there a difference in size of the datepicker when `font-size` is set to `1.5em`?
The amount of em's is not important I have tryd different font-sizes and I still get the same problem. The red box is set to 460px and is there for you to see the difference in size of the datepicker in firefox and chrome/safari.

Edit: I have already try'd using px insted of em

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firefox uses [DirectWrite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DirectWrite) to render text, and Chrome doesn't.

That is the reason for the ever so slightly different size of the rendered text.

There is no way to make *the text* pixel-perfect the same size between the two browsers.

Read this: http://www.basschouten.com/blog1.php/font-rendering-gdi-versus-directwrite

And this, **particularly** the "Hinting and spacing differences" section: http://blog.mozilla.com/nattokirai/2011/08/11/directwrite-text-rendering-in-firefox-6/

Answer (score 0):

Because 1.5em isn't a precise size and depends on what the browser decides the relevant font metrics to use are.

If you want a precise size, use either px or points.

Comment: forgot to mention that I have tryed using px insted of em's.